# Read latest post from blogspot in c#

Tags: c#, blogger

I'm trying to list the latest post from a blog (blogspot) in blogspot using c#.
I have a key that allows me to query the posts from google API.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/<blogkey>/posts?key=<mykey>
```

Any sample or help how can i do that?

Comment: Can you provide the XML or JSON that the API is returning? You'll need to grab that data from the API and map it into an object. Once it's mapped then you can grab whatever you want from it and do simple logic on it.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, using httpClient i can read the posts (url above), but i think maybe using Blogger APIs Client Library i can do that easly. I didnt found any sample how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found:

Install package:

```
Install-Package Google.Apis.Blogger.v3 -Version 1.42.0.1720
```

the code:

```
.....
using Google.Apis.Blogger.v3.Data;
.....    

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/<blogkey>/posts?key=<mykey>");          
    // Get all posts (typed as PostList) from blog.
    var postList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostList>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```